# Trimming URL in NGNIX before redirection

Tags: nginx

I am able to configure ngnix to redirect `http://mydomain/group1` to 'Group1' servers and  `http://mydomain/group2` to 'Group2' servers. But I have a requirement to trim off the group name and pass the remaining URL to the backend servers

i.e,

```
http://mydomain/group1/index.html
```

should be redirected to 'Group1' servers as `http://mydomain/index.html` and similarly for 'Group2'

is this possible?

Below is my configuration file

```
        upstream group1 
    {
        server 10.18.1.10;
    }
    upstream group2 
    {
        server 10.18.1.11;
    } 

    server 
    {
        listen       80;
        server_name  10.18.1.9;

        location /group1/ 
        {
            proxy_pass http://group1;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host       $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }

        location ~ /group2/(.*) 
        {

            proxy_pass http://group2.$http_host/$1;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host       $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;

        }

    }
```

Comment: by redirect you actually mean proxy to backend?

Comment: yes..I want the request to be served by backend servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
location ~* ^/group(\d*)/(.*) {
      proxy_pass http://group$1.$http_host/$2;
}
```

What this snipplet does is catching all the requests that match regexp pattern
`^/group(\d*)/(.*)` which says "get all that starts with /group/" while catching the numbers following Group and the trailing part after the slash into variables. The variables are numbers in order of "catching". So inside the location you can use them to rewrite a request into anything you want with "parameters" from original request. In this case you can use $1 (numbers after Group) to indicate your backend server by the hostname and $2 to maintain the trailing part. $http_host is a standard nginx reference to the "Host:" HTTP header. If you have "static" backends you can omit everything but $2 in the proxy_pass.

Comment: I appreciate your help. what does this $1 and $2 and $http_host stand for ? Can you please help me to understand what is happening here.

Comment: @FreakyThommi explained in the answer

Comment: I modified as you explained but it is saying bad gateway, Did I do it correctly ?. I have added my conf file for your reference

Comment: @FreakyThommi check what is REALLY saying in the error log. You need to see what is the resulting URL nginx is trying to fetch for you.

Comment: 2013/12/10 17:37:18 [error] 7220#0: *1135 no resolver defined to resolve group2.10.18.1.9. Do I need to use rewrite to trimoff the group1 from URL ? My configuration is attached to the question now

Comment: @FreakyThommi If you have static mapping of the backends, like the IP address in the error, then you don't need to use $1. just do http://10.18.1.9/$2

Comment: it worked; thanks a lot... But I used it this way... proxy_pass http://group1/$2;

Comment: @MichaelTabolsky Question: Why did you use capital G on "location ~ ^/Group(\d*)/(.*) {"  ? 

I'm curious, because you are doing case sensitive matching and the URL contains only lower case characters.

Comment: @alfredocambera nice catch doc. Because OP wrote "Group" a few time so its stuck in my head as a part of the input.